# Windows Phone - XmlDocument could not be found

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xmldocument

in my windows phone app I need to use XmlDocument class. But I still get errors

`Error  1   The type or namespace name 'XmlDocument' could not be found (are you    missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

I added reference and
`using System.Xml`

But it doesnt help.

This is my SOAP example code, that I need to modify to work with XDocument
**Edit - Added SOAP example code**

```
public static void CallWebService()
    {
        var _url = "http://xxxxxxxxx/Service1.asmx";
        var _action = "http://xxxxxxxx/Service1.asmx?op=HelloWorld";

        XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = CreateSoapEnvelope()
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = CreateWebRequest(_url, _action);
        InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(soapEnvelopeXml, webRequest);

        // begin async call to web request.
        IAsyncResult asyncResult = webRequest.BeginGetResponse(null, null);

        // suspend this thread until call is complete. You might want to
        // do something usefull here like update your UI.
        asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

        // get the response from the completed web request.
        string soapResult;
        using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult))
        using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
        }
        Console.Write(soapResult);
}


    private static HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest(string url, string action)
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", action);
        webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
        webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        return webRequest;
    }

    private static XmlDocument CreateSoapEnvelope()
    {
        XmlDocument soapEnvelop = new XmlDocument();
        soapEnvelop.LoadXml(@"<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema""><SOAP-ENV:Body><HelloWorld xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/"" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/""><int1 xsi:type=""xsd:integer"">12</int1><int2 xsi:type=""xsd:integer"">32</int2></HelloWorld></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>");
        return soapEnvelop;
    }

    private static void InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml, HttpWebRequest webRequest)
    {
        using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
        }
    }`
```

Comment: why are you not using Linq to Xml / XDocument instead?

Comment: Probably worth checking: [How to use webservice in Windows Phone 7 application](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/355937); [Windows Phone 7 in 7: Connecting to Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg241261.aspx); [Consuming ASMX Web Service from Windows Phone 7](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/38815099-8394-448c-80bf-a93279fbbdac/); [Creating Service Reference: Failed to generate code for the service reference](http://software-development-toolbox.blogspot.ru/2009/02/creating-service-reference-failed-to.html)

Answer (score 0):

Its [supported in WP7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx)

[image]

example with Linq is here:
http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/wp7-working-with-xml-reading-filtering-and-databinding

source code example: 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/74f20d/read-local-xml-file-from-windows-phone-7/

Comment: Ok, I get it XmlDocument doesnt exist here so I have to use XDocument. Now my problem is that I am developing SOAP based app and I have to parse XML send throught SOAP. I have here some example but I dont know how to modify it.

Comment: I am happy, that you found a solution. For you added question; I cannot read out the question. Can you rephrase it please what the question is?

Comment: My problem is that I have i C# SOAP client example, that I need to modify to work with XDocument. I can not find anywhere some working example how to do SOAP requests on WP7.